# Removing PDFs, PPTs from google custom search

Tags: google-custom-search

I want to remove all nonHTML content pages containing PPTs, DOCs ,PDFs from google custom search. I have tried various url patterns in my custom search engine , but it is still returning pdfs and ppts in search results .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Search features → Advanced → Websearch settings → Query Addition

> **Query Addition**: Appends additional query parameters to the search. Search results will
>   be served using "OR" logic. Supported values: Any search term to add to user query.

Advanced Google Site Search features
https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/3037004?hl=en

I added `-filetype:pdf -filetype:ppt -filetype:doc` and I'm not getting PDFs, DOCs, PPTs in results.

Comment: Going by my own searches, this solution is now partially broken. Oddly, the "-filetype:pdf" flag reduces the number of PDF hits while not eliminating them entirely.